# why i am getting this error "Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent." in cloudera installtion

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am installing cloudera manager on local machine.
When trying to add new host getting following error

**Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.**

- Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
- Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager server
  (check firewall rules).
- Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are free on the host being added.
- Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being
  added 
     (some of the logs can be found in the installation details).

  i checked the  logs,it shows like hostname differs from canonical name

  So I also changed the hostname from **/etc/resolv.conf**
  But still getting sam error

Comment: I run the following command

 netstat -an | grep 9000

Output is 
tcp        0      0 ::1:9000                 :::*                        LISTEN

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for a simple mistake in the file /etc/hosts :
Have you checked you have DNS and reverse DNS ?

Then to check if your port is open 7182, you should do a telnet IP 7182 (replace IP by the host of Cloudera Manager Server).

If there are still some problems, maybe you have forgotten to deactivate the firewall (iptables).

Regards, K.

Comment: hi how to check for reverse dns?.I am installing 3 node cluster on Centos7 and facing same issue of heartbeat

Comment: Well, you can write in your linux terminal > host [your IP]
for example : host 52.30.30.23
And don't forget to check the correctness of your /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you need to check first all port opened on your server service listing to the port no, use command: `sudo netstat -lpten`

Check if any thing is running on 9000 or 90001, mostly java services required for set up is running on port 9000, and cloudera-scm-agent listner also runs on port 9000. to over come this issue you can re-configure theports as well in /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini by changing as below:

```
--------------------------------------------------
## It should not normally be necessary to modify these.
# Port that the CM agent should listen on.
listening_port=9001
-------------------------------------------------
```

and then restart the cloudera-scm-agent service by command:
    `service cloudera-scm-agent restart`

To verify this port is not activated for other sshd service check Ports opened in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

I hope this resolution will work for others too.

Cheers,
Ankit Gupta